# Create stored proc to pull data from another SP with dynamic columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created an SP with dynamic pivot logic to bring in data for the number of calls made on an hourly basis. Since I have this report on different servers. Now I need to create a master SP that pulls data from this dynamic pivot table. I have defined my temp table but this breaks the report for the current day as all the buckets are not created before 12 pm for the same day. For individual reports on each server, I am inserting the dynamic Pivot table data into a temporary table. For example:

```
create table #temp( Emp_name varchar(30), calltime varchar(30), totalcall varchar(30), 
  midnighthr int not null default 0 , 1am int not null default 0, 
  2am,3am,4am, 5am, 6am, 7am,...,9pm,10pm, to 11pm)


insert into #temp
EXEC @sql

select (Emp_name, calltime , totalcall , midnighthr, 1am , 
        2am,3am,4am,5am,6am, 7am,...,9pm,10pm,to 11pm)
```

So if I run this report for DateTime: 6/24/2020 4:00 PM then this report fails because the number of columns created by @sql doesn't justify the defined columns in #temp table since we have no columns for 5 pm onwards.

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why not build the #temp create table statement based on the same logic that builds `@sql`?

Comment: Dynamic columns are only useful when data is directly consumed by reporting tools. If you need to manipulate it further afterwards it becomes difficult as you can see.
I suggest you change logic of original SPs to return either a fixed or dynamic number of columns based on SP input parameter. In you parent SP you then call these SPs specifying the parameter to eturn fixed number of columns. The extra input parameter can have a default value that tells SP to return dynamic result set, this way existing processes consuming data from these SPs will not be affected.

Comment: Hi Alex, 
Thanks for your response. My SP creates dynamic columns every time a parameter is passed through. For instance, if I use 06/23/20 as my date it might produce data generating from 7 am to 10 am (with hourly columns i.e. 7 am, 8 am, 9 am,... 10 am) or if I use 06/22/20 it might generate data from 5 pm to 9 pm (with hourly columns as 5 pm, 6 pm, 7 pm,.. 9 pm). I tried using  
CASE WHEN [2pm hr] IS NULL
   THEN 0
     ELSE [2pm hr]
  END AS [2pm hr]

Comment: I was suggesting that you modify your SP to always create a fixed number of columns based on a new parameter.

Comment: I agree with @AaronBertrand, the only way around this is to create the temp table dynamically the same as when you're trying to run the SP. In other words, before you run your SP, run the same logic to get the columns at that time, then dynamically create the temp table and then only run your SP to insert the data accordingly... If you require assistance with this, provide us with sample data and your original SP, then we'll alter it for you accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. The requirement changed and they decided to set the default to 0. I'm creating a temp table
`SET @SQL = '  SELECT wrkGrp, userID., DTName,' + @Columns + ' FROM(   SELECT tsdh.wrkGrp,tsdh.userID,SUBSTRING(tsdh.Datehour,1,10) As DTName, SUBSTRING(tsdh.Datehour,12,2) AS HourName,tsdh.CallTotal FROM #tmpsummaryDH tsdh) as PivotData PIVOT(SUM(CallTotal ) FOR HourName IN (' + @Columns + ' ) ) AS PivotResult ORDER BY wrkGrp, userID, DTName' ; INSERT INTO #tmpPivot EXEC(@SQL); SELECT  COALESCE([Midnight hr],0) AS [Midnight hr], etc`

Comment: Could you please format the code you pasted here?